# How to handle Security Alert popus in IE using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-iedriver

As part of integration testing of our JS bundle, I wrote a local HTML page which has few buttons, clicking on those either loads the JS bundle or performs different actions by calling appropriate functions in the loaded JS bundle.

I am using the IEWebDriver to automate the above mentioned scenario to test in IE, but keep getting the security popup related to the certificate error (the url to download JS bundle needs a certificate)

Security pou-up message - "The identity of the web site or the integrity of the connection cannot be verified..."

**Question** - How to handle the security popup using Selenium?

Already tried the following too but didn't work.

```
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Accept();
```

Please note that the code works for chrome without any issues but opens security popups when running in IE.

Security settings - I have already disabled the "Check for publisher's certificate revocation" and "Check for server certificate revocation" options in IE's advanced security (also restarted the computer)

Please help/guide.

Answer (score 0):

Try using TAB & Enter keystrokes using the Robot class. Not sure but might work. I was once in similar kind of situation, so Robot class & Tab keystroke solved my problem. 
Please do let us know if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This may help: 
Go to IE->Internet Options->Security-> Goto Trusted Tab-> Add your url in trusted list. 
For all Tabs(Internet, Local Intranet,Trusted  Restricted Site) please unchecked "Enable Protected Mode"

Restart your IE and check